# Why is the data disappears?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change text files to CSV format and there is some punctuation(time data like 14:25) so the np.loadtxt() can't work. Then I use the pd.read_table to read the TXT file. But there is a new problem that I am confusing.
The data is shown below:

```
08:48:25.644    26.22   26.26
08:48:26.443    26.23   26.25
08:48:27.633    26.23   26.27
08:48:28.431    26.25   26.25
08:48:29.639    26.23   26.26
08:48:30.438    26.22   26.26
08:48:31.629    26.23   26.25
08:48:32.427    26.24   26.26
08:48:33.636    26.22   26.27
08:48:34.435    26.22   26.25
08:48:35.638    26.23   26.27
08:48:36.424    26.23   26.26
08:48:37.633    26.23   26.26
08:48:38.433    26.24   26.26
08:48:39.631    26.24   26.26
```

Then I use the code shown below.

```
name = './data/up/34-up.txt'
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_table(name, header=None, delim_whitespace=True))
data.to_csv('34.csv')
```

The data can show in the CSV files.

```
         0      1      2
0   48:25.6  26.22  26.26
1   48:26.4  26.23  26.25
2   48:27.6  26.23  26.27
3   48:28.4  26.25  26.25
4   48:29.6  26.23  26.26
5   48:30.4  26.22  26.26
6   48:31.6  26.23  26.25
7   48:32.4  26.24  26.26
8   48:33.6  26.22  26.27
9   48:34.4  26.22  26.25
10  48:35.6  26.23  26.27
11  48:36.4  26.23  26.26
12  48:37.6  26.23  26.26
13  48:38.4  26.24  26.26
14  48:39.6  26.24  26.26
15  48:40.4  26.25  26.27
16  48:41.6  26.21  26.26
17  48:42.4  26.24  26.25
```

But when I use the code shown below.

```
col1 = ["time", "skin", "micro"]
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_table(name, header=None, delim_whitespace=True), columns=col1)
data.to_csv('34.csv')
```

Then the CSV file is empty except the column name is col1.

```
    time    skin    micro
0           
1           
2           
3           
4           
5           
6           
7           
8           
9           
10          
11          
12          
13          
14          
15          
16          
17
```

I don't understand what happen and why it will happens.
Can you tell me the reason? Maybe I have made some mistakes in this code?

Comment: Please, post [mre], incl sample input data.

Comment: Also _the CSV file is empty except the column name is col1_ is unclear description of the problem

Comment: I have updated the description of the question. Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
name='spam.csv'
col1 = ["time", "skin", "micro"]
data = pd.read_table(name, header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names=col1)
print(data)
data.to_csv('eggs.csv', index=False)
```

You can also use `pd.read_csv()` instead of `pd.read_table()`

`print` output

```
            time   skin  micro
0   08:48:25.644  26.22  26.26
1   08:48:26.443  26.23  26.25
...
13  08:48:38.433  26.24  26.26
14  08:48:39.631  26.24  26.26
```

the `eggs.csv`

```
time,skin,micro
08:48:25.644,26.22,26.26
08:48:26.443,26.23,26.25
...
08:48:38.433,26.24,26.26
08:48:39.631,26.24,26.26
```

EDIT: To explain better the problem - you use `pd.read_table()` that yields a DataFrame object, which you unnecessarily pass to `pd.DataFrame()` with `columns=col1`. As [stated in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for `columns` option:

> columns Index or array-like
>
> Column labels to use for resulting frame when data does not have them,
> defaulting to RangeIndex(0, 1, 2, …, n). **If data contains column
> labels, will perform column selection instead.**

As a result you get DataFrame with NaN values, and when exported to csv you get just the index and no values.

```
  time  skin  micro
0    NaN   NaN    NaN
1    NaN   NaN    NaN
2    NaN   NaN    NaN
...
13   NaN   NaN    NaN
14   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Good answer! maybe explain the difference between `columns=col1` and `names=col1` in `pd.read_table`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni, I edited my question to better explain the problem.